Short description of a software component/product?
I write documentation for a software vendor. What is the best way to describe a software component in short if we must mention both its title and function? What wording would be preferred?

the CompanyName ComponentName disk monitoring component
CompanyName ComponentName, a disk monitoring component,
CompanyName ComponentName—a disk monitoring component—
CompanyName ComponentName intended for disk monitoring
CompanyName ComponentName, which is a disk monitoring component,

...or something else?
The same goes with product titles. For example, is it OK to write "the Microsoft Office Word editor" or should we rephrase it somehow?
I suspect the best way is to describe the function of the component beforehand and than just write CompanyName ComponentName, but I'm actually doing a translation and I would like to be coherent. The original documentation is not in English and it tends to mention both CompanyName ComponentName and its function time and again. I would prefer "the CompanyName ComponentName disk monitoring component", but isn't that clunky?

Your structure examples look OK, except for the fourth one, which seems to need "which is" inserted before the description.
In American English documentation, it is probably most common to use simple    forms. That can lead to noun stacking (my term), and that can be hard to understand, especially for non-native readers. But here are some examples of the format shown above:
The Microsoft Teams collaboration app...
Adobe's Photoshop image editor...
Atlassian Jira, a bug-tracking app that runs in the cloud...
Keep in mind:
A publication or company style guide might prescribe specific formatting, punctuation, or word choices for software names and descriptions.
Names for software pieces and parts have evolved. We formerly used the terms "program", "application" (program), and "utility", most often. Now, it's more likely to see the terms app, webapp, and cloud service to describe software.
It is not entirely clear what a "component" is in the question's examples. However, in general, parts of software do have names, and you can consider the best ones to use based on the audience (how technical) and the need to be specific. You might use "component" and be understood, but you might need to use "DLL" (dynamic link library) or "framework" or "API" or "files" or "software code" to identify specific parts or functions of software. You would use terms such as "class", "method", "function" and "interface" when writing about specific sections of code in object-oriented programming, just as an example of different names that can apply to software.
Usually, when terms or names must be repeated, we often end up using abbreviations or shortened names. This should always be explained in an "about this document" section, or, at least, where the term is used for the first time.

Look at how this is commonly done in similar writings for the same audience. If there are different approaches, put each of them – and your own ideas – in short sample texts and compare their effects and comprehensibility. If you have no clear preference yourself, get feedback from members of your target audience – or ask your boss what (s)he wants.
In short, identify conventions, evaluate them, and get user feedback.

Yes, but be careful because the mere fact that a style is common within a community doesn’t ensure that it is effective, or clear. Instead, it is often the case that typical authors in a community simply are not skilled at writing. For instance, in some communities one encounters a lot of noun-noun modification. That’s what’s going on in your final example, and it’s what makes it seem “clunky” to you. Your instinct to unroll such lengthy chains of noun phrases is exactly how one can eliminate them. Gut health maintenance system can become system to maintain the health of one’s gut.

"Gut health maintenance system can become system to maintain the health of one’s gut." That's true, but what if such expression occurs a dozen of times through text? The length and wordiness of frequent "unrolled" phrases become another issue.

@PeterS. You replied to me, not to Paul Tanenbaum. Use @PaulTanenbaum to address him directly.

(Now that I have happened upon OP’s follow-up question) Yes, @PeterS, that’s true. One option is to explicitly introduce a suitably brief term and thereafter use it instead.
